# What is $\Im\Big(\frac{e^{(i-t)x}}{i-t}\Big)$?

Tags: real-analysis, integration

> What is $\Im\Big(\frac{e^{(i-t)x}}{i-t}\Big)$? (Imaginary part of the expression in the parentheses, where $t$ is constant )

Actually this was an integral exercise ($\int_0^\infty \sin(x) e^{-tx}dx$), which can also be solved with Integration by parts (what i did), but  i saw also this method using Euler's formula and i think this looks much easier and faster than IBP, only if i could knew how to write it as a real fraction.

$\Im\Big(\frac{e^{(i-t)x}}{i-t}\Big)=\Im\Big(\frac{(i+t)e^{(i-t)x}}{(i+t)(i-t)}\Big)=\frac{-1}{1+t^2}\Im\Big((i+t)e^{(i-t)x}\Big)= ?$

now I'm stuck, what is $(i+t)$ in the parentheses, how can i get rid of it ?

Comment: Nevermind. The thing I did didn't work because the number in the $\sin$ wasn't real.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use $$\frac{1}{i-t} = \frac{-i-t}{(i-t)(-i-t)} = \frac{-i-t}{1+t^2}$$
Hence
$$\begin{eqnarray}
   \Im\left(\frac{\exp\left(x (i-t)\right)}{i-t}\right) &=& \Im\left(\frac{\left(-i-t\right)\exp\left(x (i-t)\right)}{1+t^2}\right) \\ &=& \frac{\exp(-t x)}{1+t^2} \Im\left(\left(-i-t\right)\exp\left(i x \right)\right) \\ &&= \frac{\exp(-t x)}{1+t^2} \left(-t \sin(x) - \cos(x)\right)
\end{eqnarray}$$

Comment: This looks very nice, but it was not really too faster than IBP, like i thought.